# addEventListener to window and document object.

Tags: javascript

I expect 2 alert windows. But I only got one "window ready" alert. why the document load handler not working?

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { alert('window ready')});
document.addEventListener('load', function(){ alert('document ready')});
```

if I change the code to

```
window.addEventListener("load",  alert('window ready'));
document.addEventListener('load',  alert('document ready'));
```

Then I see 2 alert boxes. Did I make any stupid mistake or have the wrong assumption?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `document` doesn't have a `load` event.

Comment: You're probably looking for `DOMContentLoaded` event

Comment: @SLaks, I got 2 alert boxes in the second block of code, so I think document has load event, doesn't it?

Comment: @elclanrs, do you know which event does $(document).ready() listen to?

Comment: _“I got 2 alert boxes in the second block of code, so I think document has load event, doesn't it?”_ – no. There you are just calling the `alert` method right there and then, so it gets executed immediately, and has no connection to any events whatsoever. (addEventListener expects a function _reference_, but you are executing a function and are just passing its empty return value instead. If you are not aware what the difference between referencing and calling a function is, please go read up on that.)

Comment: @CBroe, thank you very much for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ready.promise = function( obj ) {
    if ( !readyList ) {

        readyList = jQuery.Deferred();

        // Catch cases where $(document).ready() is called after the browser event has already occurred.
        // we once tried to use readyState "interactive" here, but it caused issues like the one
        // discovered by ChrisS here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12282#comment:15
        if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
            // Handle it asynchronously to allow scripts the opportunity to delay ready
            setTimeout( jQuery.ready );

        } else {

            // Use the handy event callback
            document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", completed, false );

            // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
            window.addEventListener( "load", completed, false );
        }
    }
    return readyList.promise( obj );
};
```

Here are the original jQuery code. It looks like there is no "ready" event name on document object. 
"DOMContentLoaded" event is only valid in HTML5.